# An 'increasing Edge' in a network flow

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

> We are given a network flow, as well as a max flow in the network. An edge would be called **increasing edge** if increasing its capacity in an arbitrary positive number, would also increase the max flow.
>
> Present an algorithm the finds an increaing edge (if one exists) and runs at $O(n^2)$.

I thought about the following idea -

- Find the minimum cut in the graph, as its given to us with the ford-fulkerson algorithm.
- Increase the capacity of all the edges in the left hand side of the cut by 1.
- Run BFS in the residual network to find if an improved path exists. If one exists, we have an increasing edge. To find it, we have to compare the original network with the new network. **We have to do that n times since we have to check for an improved path every time we increase the capacity by 1.**

Is it correct, an am I in line with the required running time?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to find a path from the source to the sink that *would* be an augmenting path if at most one node were increased in capacity.

First find all the best paths to vertices you can reach with residual capacity.  If you found the sink, then you weren't given a max flow to begin with.

Then find all the other vertices that are adjacent to those ones though edges that are at capacity.

Then try to find an augmenting path from those vertices to the sink.

Total complexity is O(N), so whoever asked you this question probably had something else in mind.